# Using jQuery to adjust min-height based on content inside div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am a total newb to jquery and I want to know how to add a way for jquery to adjust the min-height of a div based on how much content is inside it. I will always want the min-height to probably be around 700, but as users add more content on some pages, it needs to stretch to fit that content.

How do I integrate this? please be specific, in terms of css, html, etc as I am new to jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Too simple:

HTML

```
<div class="foo" >
This is sample<br />
This is sample<br />
This is sample<br />
This is sample<br />
This is sample<br />
This is sample<br />
This is sample<br />
</div>​
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $(".foo").css("min-height", function() {
        return $(this).height();
    });
});
```

Comment: is "min-height" a selector as well?

Comment: No, its just a property in the jQuery `.css()` method. (_[More details](http://api.jquery.com/css/)_)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand you, you don't need to adjust min-height as users add content; elements with a min-height property will automatically grow to fit the content they contain. So you shouldn't have to worry about it.

For example: if you apply the css property `min-height: 700px` in your stylesheet, on pages where they is 500px of content inside the element, the element will be 700px height; on pages where there is 900px of content, the element will be 900px high.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yeah, for some reason when I scroll up and then scroll back down, my background image has been pushed up and I can see the body color

Comment: Sounds like you've got css issues unrelated to the min-height property; changing the height with jQuery as outlined in other answers may help but it's probably just a band-aid if that's the case. If you're testing in an older version of IE, you may also have found a rendering bug, in which case a band-aid may be a good option... min-height does work as advertised though.

Comment: Try simplifying your CSS or HTML structure; adding jQuery to set a detected height on page load is a clunky workaround, and may require other complications (e.g. you'll need to recalc if the browser is subsequntly resized)

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. The min-height is working, but I have divs that have to be added in via absolute position. So, it pushes down the body? or html? but not the div because technically it is not in that div. Is there a way to get the body or html height to match the min-height?